# is there other way of writing range

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, worksheet-function

hi for example i have to write this in my formula

```
  Sheet1!A1:HM232
```

is there any other way of writing this (for example using only numbers, without any letters)

```
  Sheet1!Cells[1,1]:Cells[232,221]
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Switch to R1C1 notation in Excel parameters.

Comment: every time i select the same range it changes the rc values which makes me crazy...

for example for the first time it shows
    {=Sheet1!R[-7]C[-2]:R[-6]C[-1]+Sheet1!R[-7]C[1]:R[-6]C[2]}
in the second time it shows
    {=Sheet1!R[-7]C[-5]:R[-6]C[-4]+Sheet1!R[-7]C[-2]:R[-6]C[-1]}
third time i copy the same range now it shows
     {=Sheet1!R[-11]C[-2]:R[-10]C[-1]+Sheet1!R[-11]C[1]:R[-10]C[2]}

Comment: i switched to normal way now it all three cases it shows only
    {=Sheet1!B6:C7+Sheet1!E6:F7}
which is much clearer

Comment: probably i have to read about the RC, it seems to be doing everything correctly, thanks!

Comment: You should try changing the referencing to absolute - the craziness disappears. You get either `{=Sheet1!$B$6:$C$7+Sheet1!$E$6:$F$7}` or `{=Sheet1!R6C2:R7C3+Sheet1!R6C5:R7C6}`. Much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

In VBA you can reference like so:

```
Set R = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(232, 231))
```

In a Worksheet you can use the following formula which just requires you to have the initial cell reference (as an 'A1' style reference):

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,0,232,221))
```